# Pandas multiindex subset selection

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have Python 3.6 and Pandas 19.0. I am playing around with multi indices for dataframes.

```
iterables = [['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two', 'three','four']]
pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['first', 'second'])
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux', 'bar', 'foo']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])]
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10), index=arrays)
```

I know how to get a subset based on a single value for one of the indices, e.g.

```
s.loc[s.index.get_level_values(0)=='bar']
Out[16]: 
                  0
bar one    1.409395
    two    0.837486
    three  1.290018
```

How can I get a subset based on a set of values corresponding to a single index? Obviously the syntax below does not work:

```
my_subset = set(['three', 'one'])
s.loc[s.index.get_level_values(1) in my_subset]
```

**EDIT:**

What would be the fastest solution for a large data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) and select second level by `1`:

```
my_subset = set(['three', 'one'])
a = s.loc[s.index.get_level_values(1).isin(my_subset)]
print (a)

                  0
bar one   -0.372206
baz one    0.886271
foo one   -2.231380
qux one    0.960636
bar three  1.272873
```

**Perrfomance**: It depends of number of matched values and number of rows:

```
N = 10000
a = ['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux']
b = ['one', 'two', 'three','four']
arrays = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([np.random.choice(a, size=N),
                                     np.random.choice(b, size=N)], names=['first', 'second'])

s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(N), index=arrays).sort_index()
print (s)

my_subset1 = set(['three', 'one'])
my_subset2 = ['three', 'one']

In [209]: %timeit s.loc[s.index.get_level_values(1).isin(my_subset1)]
866 µs ± 59.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [210]: %timeit s.query('second in @my_subset2')
2.19 ms ± 47.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Ah! of course. thank you for the fast response. will accept in 10 mins

Comment: @Rhubarb - added test with sample data.

Comment: That is perfect, thank you so much for taking the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) your dataframe. Assuming, as in your example, the second level of your index is named `second`:

```
my_subset = ['three', 'one']

res = s.query('second in @my_subset')
```